# "But (something) instead" versus "but instead (something)"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order

Please consider the sentences:

> They do not overpower the city, *but empower it instead*.
>
> They do not overpower the city, *but instead empower it*.

I'm doubting the use of *but + instead*. Is either incorrect syntactically? If not, which one reads better? NB: it is for an academic paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both correct syntactically. In terms of style, the best sentence to use for your purpose is the one with **instead** in the end.

Comment: +1 because they are both correct syntactically. The comment about style, though, is completely subjective.

Comment: Note that if there were a long phrase replacing *"empower it"*, you would definitely want to use *"but instead ..."*.

Comment: The *instead* is just an intensifier: "They do not overpower the city, but empower it." would work, as would "They do not overpower, but empower, the city."

Answer (score 0):

The first expression is correct by itself.
The second one would be correct with a comma:
*...city, but instead, empower it.*

In the second instance, you may see a slight difference of meaning or shift of emphasis.
Syntactically they would be very different I suppose.

Comment: The use of commas here would be a matter of style, not of syntax.